# Firebase web get provider data (gender and birthday ) in Google and Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Herer is my Google part

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().languageCode = 'zh-TW';
provider.addScope('profile');
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me');
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read');
provider.addScope('email');
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.user)
}).catch(function(error) {
    app.message.register = error.message;
});
```

Herer is my Facebook part

```
 var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('user_birthday');
    firebase.auth().languageCode = 'zh-TW';
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {

      console.log(result.user)

    }).catch(function(error) {

    });
```

Those two part are not get the gender and birthday in `console.log(result.user)` is there missing some setting ? or having the wrong part? Any idea?

Comment: that´s a bit too broad, both platforms are a bit different. do you know about login review on facebook? do you get asked for the birthday permission in the login process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The access tokens returned `result.credential.accessToken` will provide access to these additional scopes. You would need to query the Google/Facebook API with that access token to get this data (specific to the additional requested scopes). By the way, some additional user info is now returned specific to IdP. Check content of `result.additionalUserInfo.profile`.

Comment: Can you provide a example query? in result.additionalUserInfo is not birthdate or gender

Comment: Try use this awesome tool to get how to use the APIs 

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground